# Unix time stamp conversion in Azure synapse analytics

Tags: azure-synapse

I am using the below script to do refining the data in silver layer:

```
 # Read from existing internal table
 dfAsset =(spark.read.option(Constants.SERVER,"xyz.sql.azuresynapse.net")
.synapsesql("abc.Salesforce.Asset")       
.select("Id","ContactId","CreatedDate","CreatedById","LastModifiedDate")
.filter(col("productCode").contains("11061164")).limit(10))
 dfAsset.show()

 For particular column CreatedDate the data is appearing in the Unix format.Please refer 
 the below :

CreateDate
1652108980000
1632313243000
1632312269000
1632312410000

I need to convert the data into YYYY-MM-DD. In the above script

Please advise how it can be done.
```

Regards
RK

Answer (score 0):

This is my sample Dataframe saved in the variable `dfAsset`.

```
#+-----------+
#|   date1   |
#+-----------+
#|16521089   |
#|16323132   |
#|16323122   |
#|16323124   |
#+-----------+
```

**Using below code you can convert the data into YYYY-MM-DD.**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,to_date
df = dfAsset.withColumn('date',to_date(col('date1').cast(TimestampType()))) 
df.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: The cast(TimestampType()) is not supported in synaspe analytics notebook.Please advise

Comment: The above code is executed in synapse notebook itself. Please import the TimestampType first and then try again.

Comment: I have other columns in the dataframe

Comment: Please edit and provide other columns on above dataframe

Comment: from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,to_date
df = dfAsset.withColumn('CreatedDate',to_date(col('Created_Date').cast(TimestampType()))
             .select("productCode","Id","ContactId","AccountId","ParentId","RootAssetId","CreatedById")) 
df.show()  I am getting error TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable  .

Comment: @RohitKulkarni, For information please follow this [link](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-to_date-convert-timestamp-to-date/)

Comment: if you already have `CreatedDate` then no need to select all columns try this use this code from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType 
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,to_date 
`df = dfAsset.withColumn('CreatedDate',to_date(col('Created_Date').cast(TimestampType())))
df.show()`